# File name completion relative to currently edited file

Tags: autocompletion

If I open a file that isn't in the current directly, when I used Vim to autocomplete a filename, Vim provides files relative to the location where I launched Vim, not the currently edited file.

Example

```
$ find .
  nice-file.xml
  xml/
      messy-file.xml
      ok-file.xml
$ vim xml/messy-file.xml
```

Now if I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, Vim provides "nice-file.xml" as a complete option. It doesn't offer ok-file.xml, even though it's in the same directory as the file I'm currently editing.

I'd like Vim to complete filenames relative to whatever file I'm editing. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `:cd` in Vim to change the current directory:

```
:cd xml
```

Or more generally, if you want to set it sometimes:

```
nnoremap gp :cd %:p:h<CR>
```

Or if you want to always be in the current file's directory:

```
set autochdir
```

Please note that this may break some plugins, because they may rely on the current directory, you can use in place:

```
autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h
```

---

If you don't want to change the current directory, you can also add the current folder to your completion path:

```
autocmd BufRead *
  \ let s:tempPath=escape(escape(expand("%:p:h"), ' '), '\ ') |
  \ exec "set path+=".s:tempPath
```

Comment: I cringe at overriding the wonderfully useful `gf` mapping. I would suggest overriding something like `gs` or maybe using a `<leader>` mapping

Comment: if a plugin does not handle `acd` it better be fixed. But that BufEnter workaround shouldn't be neccessary anymore

Comment: `autochdir` was exactly what I was looking for. It doesn't seem to be conflicting at all with my modest plugin selection.